# Why doesn't my MySQL query work?

Tags: mysql

Why doesn't my MySQL query work?

---

#### Query:

```
DELETE FROM jos_community_awards a
LEFT JOIN jos_community_users u
ON a.userId = u.userid WHERE a.points > u.points;
```

---

#### Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that >corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a
> LEFT JOIN jos_community_users u
> ON a.userId = u.userid
> WHERE a.points > u.poi' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you can't delete from an alias.  Or you need to specify the entire row so a.*  I think you need to specify the entire row with .* either on the table name or the alias.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you! I never expected you'd have to specify the columns in a delete.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE queries with joins are bit tricky. Adding the table name after the `DELETE` keyword should help if I remember correctly:

```
DELETE jos_community_awards FROM jos_community_awards ...
```